# .htaccess rewriting subdomain + folder to uri

Tags: linux, apache, http, .htaccess

I want to redirect this:

`subdom.mydom.com/mydoc`

TO

`mydom.com/subdom/mydoc.php`

Sorry for being too obvious. I know the htaccess rewriting basis but this is making me a little crazy :)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]
```

-- http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never done any mod_rewrite stuff, but I imagine the regexes might look a bit like this:

Match:

```
([^\.]*).mydom.com/(.*)
```

Redirect to:

```
mydom.com/$1/$2.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but it would be something like this (assuming you want all /whatever to redirect to /whatever.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.mydom\.com/(.+) mydom.com/$1/$2.php
```